# Distribution of exponential divided by sum of exponentials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm having trouble solving the following problem. Suppose $X=(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ are independent, identically distributed random variables with $X_{i}\sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda=1)$, that is, $f_{X_{i}}(x)=e^{-x}I_{[0,\infty)}$. I am interested in the distribution of $Y=(Y_{1},...,Y_{n})$, where $Y_{i}=X_{i}/\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$. I was trying to solve it by the usual theorem for measurable transformations of random vectors, but somehow I cannot invert the transformation above given. Is there really *no way* to solve a problem so apparently easy?

Comment: A guess (without checking) is that this might be the same distribution as a uniform distribution on a simplex, so a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) with $\alpha=1$.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for answering! How does this change if one defines Yi:=nXi/∑ni=1Xi, where n is the total number of random variables in the random vector X? Is it just the same but over [0,n]?

Comment: Your notation is difficult to read, but if you multiply by $n$ then yes, it is a scaled version of what it would be unscaled

Comment: Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36093/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wait $n$ times for something to happen that has the same probability of happening at any given moment. Given that the $n$-th event occurs at time $S$, what’s the distribution of the times of the other $n-1$ events? Since they had the same chance of occurring at any time, they’re uniformly distributed over $[0,S]$. If you now divide by $S$, they’re uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. The $Y_i$ are the differences between these $n$ normalized times (including the $n$-th, which was normalized to $1$). So as Henry guessed, they follow a [flat Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104377/discussion-on-answer-by-joriki-distribution-of-exponential-divided-by-sum-of-exp).